# Can I install a pre-downloaded image of Raspbian Stretch with NOOBS Lite?

Tags: noobs, raspbian-stretch

I have downloaded Raspbian Strech OS and also I have downloaded NOOBS Lite. Can I install Raspbian Stretch through NOOBS Lite offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can download NOOBS_Lite (https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_lite_latest), unzip it and write all files and folders to the SD card. On the SD card there is a folder (directory) `os`. Create another folder (directory) `Raspbian` and/or `Raspbian_Lite` in the `os` folder (ie `os/Raspbian` and/or `os/Raspbian_Lite`). Download the following files from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian and/or https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite.

**Raspbian.png, boot.tar.xz, os.json, partition_setup.sh, partitions.json,** and **root.tar.xz**

And place then on the SD card in folder `os/Raspbian` and/or `os/Raspbian_Lite`.
This SD card should boot up in the Raspberry Pi as mine did.

NOTE: The SD card should have only one DOS (VFAT) partition for the whole card. New SD cards 32GB or less are formatted this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, if you create a custom OS version**.

You can [create a custom OS version for use with NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/Adding-custom-OS-version-examples), and include that with NOOBS Lite. This custom OS version will include the image, so no network connection will be required. The documentation specifies that a Linux PC is required to do this, and provides step-by-step commands that you may follow.

Note that if you don't do this, though, according to the [NOOBS documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md):

> The full version has Raspbian included, so it can be installed from the SD card while offline, whereas **using NOOBS Lite or installing any other operating system requires an internet connection.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

You will need the full version of NOOBS, not NOOBS Lite, if you wish to install Raspbian offine, **unless you add a custom OS version to NOOBS Lite**.